# How to load xml files into mysql via python?

Tags: python, mysql

```
def loadOldXml(path):
     global ppszJsonStackPerDev
     ppszJsonStackPerDev = {}
     print 'Loading old XMLs from "' + path + '"...'
     pszFiles = filter( lambda f: os.path.isfile( os.path.join( path, f)), os.listdir( path))

    pszFiles.sort(reverse=True)
```

It is loading a set of xml files

```
    for f in pszFiles:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch( f, dump_prefix + "_*.xml") == False:
           continue
        cnx = MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd='024896', host='127.0.0.1', db='eha')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        psz = f.split( "_", 3)  
        if not psz[1] in ppszJsonStackPerDev:
           ppszJsonStackPerDev[ psz[1]] = []

        print '"' + os.path.join( path, f) + '"'

        ppszJsonStackPerDev[ psz[1]].append( Measurement(
        DataList( os.path.join( path, f), True)).describe())
        add_bodyfat = ("INSERT INTO bodyfat "
         "(UserId, BodyMass, Height, BMI, BodyFat, RestingMetabolism, VFatLvl, BodyAge, SkeletalMuscle, Date) "
         "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        data_bodyfat = "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE" + path + "INTO BODYFAT nodes"
        cursor.execute(add_bodyfat, data_bodyfat)
        cnx.commit()
        cnx.close()
```

Unable to load xml files into mysql database
There is this error: not enough arguments for format string (near cursor.execute)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data-list>
   <entry>
      <meta-data>
         <meta name="personal-id">52</meta>
         <meta name="HANDLE">1</meta>
      </meta-data>
      <compound>
         <name>Numeric</name>
         <entries>
            <entry>
               <meta-data>
                  <meta name="partition">2</meta>
                  <meta name="metric-id">57664</meta>
                  <meta name="unit-code">1731</meta>
                  <meta name="unit">kg</meta>
               </meta-data>
               <simple>
                  <name>Simple-Nu-Observed-Value</name>
                  <type>float</type>
                  <value>59.400002</value>
               </simple>
            </entry>
            <entry>
               <compound>
                  <name>Absolute-Time-Stamp</name>
                  <entries>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>century</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>20</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>year</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>15</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>month</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>1</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>day</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>9</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>hour</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>8</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>minute</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>4</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>second</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>0</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                     <entry>
                        <simple>
                           <name>sec_fractions</name>
                           <type>intu8</type>
                           <value>0</value>
                        </simple>
                     </entry>
                  </entries>
               </compound>
            </entry>
         </entries>
      </compound>
   </entry>
</data-list>
```

one small portion of my xml files. My xml files are all stored in a datalist

Comment: Thanks, you've posted your code.
Can you also edit your question to explain why your code is failing?

Comment: Edit your question, and add explanation regarding what problem are you facing with this code?

Comment: At which line in the code are you getting that error?

Comment: near cursor.execute()

Comment: What does the XML file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your code should not be combining an `INSERT` with a `LOAD XML`.  Try this instead:

```
data_bodyfat = "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' INTO TABLE BODYFAT"
cursor.execute(data_bodyfat)
```